# Error: SIGABRT Signal meaning : Aborted" when trying to connect to the database by QT on UBUNTU

Tags: c++, mysql, database, qt

Error:

The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the Operating System.

Signal name : 
SIGABRT
Signal meaning : 
Aborted

Code Snippet:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDir>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QSqlDriver>
#include <qsqldatabase.h>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QPluginLoader>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QSqlDatabase db= QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setDatabaseName("NNF");
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setPassword("123456");
    if( !db.open() )
    {
        qDebug() << db.lastError();
        qFatal( "Failed to connect." );
    }

    qDebug( "Connected!" );
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Do you have any output? Which line causes the cradh? (Comment out lines to find out).

Comment: Also, look at the terminal output. It may be that the database isn't opening, the error message is being printed out to the terminal, and the call to `qFatal` is causing your program to close.